# How to further filter a data frame after using groupby and value counts

Tags: python

I am currently working with a huge data set and I am having some trouble filtering the data. I have a data frame that is something like

```
Name  Activity
John  Cleaning
Mary  Driving
Peter Cleaning 
John  Driving
```

and so on for a million rows. I applied `df.groupby('Name')['activity'].valuecounts()` and got a data frame that looks like

```
Name  Activity
John  Cleaning 3
      Driving  2
      Walking  1
Mary  Cleaning 1
      Driving  1 
      Walking  1
Peter Cleaning 1
```

I would like to further filter this by extracting only those names that have a maximun value count for activities greater than 1 but I am not sure how to do it. I.e in this example I only want to get John as an output I would appreciate any help

Comment: Your desired output isn't clear. Could you add it to the question?

Comment: Yes definetly, sorry about that. My desired output is only the names that performed activities more than 1 time i.e from the example gave I want to have john only as my output. if there is a better way of doing this without using the group by would be good too

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

If every row looks like `Name Activity` and there are no other columns, then what you're actually looking to do is filter the names based on whether they are included in any duplicate rows. One way to do this is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["John",  "Cleaning"], 
     ["John",  "Cleaning"], 
     ["Mary", "Driving"], 
     ["Mary", "Cleaning"], 
     ["Mary", "Walking"], 
     ["John", "Driving"],
     ["Peter", "Cleaning"], 
     ["John", "Driving"], 
     ["John", "Cleaning"],
     ["John", "Walking"]],
     columns=["Name", "Activity"])

result = df[
  df['Name'].isin(df[df.duplicated()]['Name'])
  ].groupby('Name')['Activity'].value_counts()

print(result)
```

If you do have other columns you're just not showing here, you can use `duplicated(subset=["Name", "Activity"])`.

Output:

```
Name  Activity
John  Cleaning    3
      Driving     2
      Walking     1
```

**EDIT**

If all you need are the names and none of the activities, you can use

```
df[df.duplicated()]['Name'].unique()
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry to bother again. Your code worked perfect but I want to get as an output only john. how do I get only the names out of this series? Than you so much!

Comment: Oh that is easier: `df[df.duplicated()]['Name'].unique()`

Comment: result = df[
  df['Name'].isin(df[df.duplicated()]['Name'].unique())
  ].groupby('Name')['Activity'].value_counts()                                                                                                     but I still gwt in return alld the activities that each name performed

Comment: Do you see my comment? It’s different if you just want the names

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I did not explain my desired outcome well enough. The first code you put filtered the data frame as I wanted it. However, out of that filter, I wanted to extract the group names. It creates a series and I don't know how to filter a series. I decided to do it this way `result = df.groupby(['Name','Activity']).size().reset_index(name='count')
result = result[result['count'] > 1]
result.drop(columns=['Activity','count'],inplace=True)` Is there a way to extract the names with your code? Thank you again

Comment: Did you see where I wrote `df[df.duplicated()]['Name'].unique()` above? That will give you an array. You can wrap that in `pd.DataFrame(...)` or `pd.Series(...)` depending on what you need

Comment: ohhh okay, I get it now. Thank you for your patience